# First and last value of grouped series

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and I would like to create two columns containing respectively the first value of a group for column and the last value of the same group but for another column.

My df looks like this :

```
   one  two    ID  number
0  AAA  BBB  idx1       1
1  BBB  CCC  idx1       2
2  DDD  EEE  idx2       1
3  CCC  KKK  idx1       3
```

And I want to create a column `first`that contains the first `one` of each group (grouped by `ID`), and a column `last`that contains the last `two` of each group. Everything sorted by `number`column (and grouped by `ID`.

So the output should look like :

```
   one  two    ID  number first last
0  AAA  BBB  idx1       1   AAA  KKK
1  BBB  CCC  idx1       2   AAA  KKK
2  DDD  EEE  idx2       1   DDD  EEE
3  CCC  KKK  idx1       3   AAA  KKK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and then append by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = (df.join(df.sort_values(['ID','number'])
                .groupby('ID')
                .agg(first=('one','first'),last= ('two','last')), on='ID'))
print (df)
   one  two    ID  number first last
0  AAA  BBB  idx1       1   AAA  KKK
1  BBB  CCC  idx1       2   AAA  KKK
2  DDD  EEE  idx2       1   DDD  EEE
3  CCC  KKK  idx1       3   AAA  KKK
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! I need to learn how to use .join and .agg